# Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type - sometimes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, built-in

I'm trying to send built-in like, but I getting this:
"Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type"

It happens only on some pages. Here fails:

```
curl -F 'access_token=UR_TOKEN' \
     -F 'object=http://stylowi.pl/594206' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes'
```

Here works great:

```
curl -F 'access_token=UR_TOKEN' \
     -F 'object=http://stylowi.pl/146306' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes'
```

Why? The same types, types... Looks identically.

Here like doesn't work: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstylowi.pl%2F594206

Here like works: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstylowi.pl%2F596269

So why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by page 594206 requiring the [Like Button Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/), and page 146306 not requiring the migration.

Pay particular attention to this sentence in that doc:

"A Facebook admin page will no longer be created for any **new** Open Graph object page that is annotated with a Like Button social plugin"

So, I suspect page 594206 was scraped before the migration announcement (requiring migration) and 146306 was scraped after the announcement.