# Built-in like action rejects the object type

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

First of all, can someone confirm that open graph object types form a hierarchy. I mean is every `movie` a `video` and is every `video` an `object`?

The reason I'm asking is that `like` action type supports only defining `object` object type in the app dashboard so if I define my object to be of type `movie`, will I be able to like that object? From what I can gather from documentation, that should indeed be the case, but it is not stated anywhere explicitly.

I stumbled upon this because I get an error while trying to like a URL on behalf of a user. The liked object instance has the `og:type` defined as `movie`. The error returned is:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

I tried several things and I got really confusing results:

1. I tried changing the `og:type` parameter to `object`. I got the same error.
2. I tried changing the `og:type` parameter to `website`. I got the same error.
3. I tried changing the `og:type` parameter to `video`. I got the same error.
4. I tried changing the id query parameter in the URL that is passed as an object to like. That causes my web app on the server to not find the object referenced by id and in turn not render any meta tags. According to the debugger, type is determined implicitly as 'website'. This works in a sense that I get an id of the action instance, and trying the same request again throws an error that the connection already exists. However, nothing shows in either the news feeds or in Likes in user profile. I can delete the connection normally.
5. I tried supplying an URL that can not be resolved by DNS. The debugger says it can't scrape any information. Otherwise, the same happens as in case 4.

Some more info about my setup:

- The app is configured to publish the `Like` action type, and `Object` and `Video` object types.
- I don't have a canvas URL defined since my app is self hosted elsewhere and no facebook page is needed.
- The `Like` action type has not been submitted for approval but I'm performing requests with a valid access token from a user that has a role to perform the non-submitted action-types in my app.
- The access token is long-lived, obtained by exchanging the short-lived access token received when user authenticated through the client-side authentication flow.
- The user has authenticated after the published action types and object types have been defined.
- All the tests have been performed from both the Open Graph Explorer and Fiddler on my machine, with parameters (`object` and `access_token`) urlencoded.
- If using the like social plugin, everything works as expected.

[possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033957/like-actions-are-not-yet-supported-against-objects-of-this-type-sometimes) question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `website` is fine.

Try doing the [Like Button Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/), see "Preparing for Migration" in that doc.

You can check if your `website` needs the migration by checking if it has the old-style "Admin Page" for that `website` (object) by checking if you are admin for a FB Page with the same name as the `og:site-name` or `og:title` meta tag.  If you are admin for a FB Page named the same as your object, then like'ing using Open Graph (ie. with `/me/og.likes`) requires Like Button Migration.