# (#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type - android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Hello im trying to use in my android app like button for facebook.

I looked here for the code facebook provides:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes

and here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/#publishing

I added this type:

[image]

This is my android code:

```
class LikeTigoFacebook extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

            Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("object",
                    "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Tigo/535949156477655");

            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                    "me/og.likes", params, HttpMethod.POST);
            Response response = request.executeAndWait();

            Log.i("check", response.getError().getErrorMessage());
            Log.i("check2", response.toString());

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Void file_url) {

        }
    }
```

And i get this error codes:

```
(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.
```

and to full string from the response is:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.}, isFromCache:false}
```

My session is opened and i added this permissions when the user logged in:

```
private void onClickLogin() {

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(RegisterPage.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

        if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

        } else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Ask for username and password
            OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(
                    (Activity) RegisterPage.this);

            op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            op.setCallback(null);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("email");
            permissions.add("publish_actions");
            op.setPermissions(permissions);

            Session session = new Session.Builder(RegisterPage.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForPublish(op);
        }
    }
```

I tried to look here:

[Built-in like action rejects the object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203514/built-in-like-action-rejects-the-object-type)

Its does not help me it seems like an old answer.

Thank for helping

Comment: You can not like Facebook pages with the `og.likes` action – as stated in the docs, this action is for Open Graph objects only.

Comment: Open Graph objects are _external_ URLs – not Facebook-internal URLs like fanpages.

Comment: So i cant like pages with this method?

Comment: Congratulations, now you counted 1 and 1 together.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the Open Graph 'Like' action to post likes for Facebook Pages

See the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/):
The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.

And a question here explaining this: 
['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: Is there any other way this can be done? other than having a like in webview. Because I am using FB sdk for signing to FB to do fb post and even if the user has active FBSession, inorder to like a page user has to sign-in again in the webview session.